# MS Access Report: how to repeat the last record of a group in the footer

Tags: ms-access, report, footer

MS Access 2016(?)

I have a section of a report that displays footers.
I want to repeat the last record of the group in the footer.  I don't need a running sum, or total, or count, or max.  I just want to display the last record of each group.

e.g. if students work at their own pace, and teacher wants to see the score of their last chapter test. (just an example)

Will Max of Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4, etc work?  Doesn't seem to because of all the calculations.

Here is my Problem

1) I have a query that pools and calculates results from a few tables.  The query has IIFs and function calls to code I've written to add to the results.

2) The query accurately displays the results in each row

3) The report will show results fine line by line.

4) **But** in a group of results, I only want to show the last results. 
 (sometimes a group has two rows of data, sometimes only one)

Comment: An expression in textbox in group footer will display value from last record for the group definition. So if your group is by first letter of last name then the footer will show data from last record and if that record is for Zagreb, then Zagreb will show `=[LastName]`. If you want last record for each letter of alphabet then will likely need a subreport.

Comment: Unfortunately, I found that it was repeatedly and persistently showing the value of the first record in the group.   From your example =[LastName] was the first LastName in the group.  For example Adams would be displayed, not Zetter.  And then if I sorted by LastName Desc, it would still show the first LastName (Adams) in the group, even though the display was now Desc with Zetter displayed first and then Adams.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I did not set up my test report correctly. Try: `=Last([LastName])`. And correction, it shows data from last record under EACH group. Sort order in report design is applicable.

Comment: Thank you.  How do I leave a comment indicating you are a swell person and give you some thumbs-upishness?

Comment: If my suggestion worked, I could write an answer and you could accept and upvote it. You can give comment an 'upvote' as well to indicate it was a useful comment.